# download image from webpage using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to download image from the webpage.
View source shows the html code as

```
<td><a href="javascript:parent.ShowImage(&#34;247246803&#34;, &#34;0&#34;, &#34;Vehicle 2 - Front&#34;, &#34;l. 1/2&#34;,&#34;jpg&#34;)"><img width="100px" height="78px" alt="l. 1/2" src="GetBinary.aspx?Image&amp;ImageID=247246803&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=0"></a><div style="text-align:center;height:50px">l. 1/2</div></td>

<td><a href="javascript:parent.ShowImage(&#34;247246783&#34;, &#34;0&#34;, &#34;Vehicle 2 - Front&#34;, &#34;c6&#34;,&#34;jpg&#34;)"><img width="100px" height="78px" alt="c6" src="GetBinary.aspx?Image&amp;ImageID=247246783&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=0"></a><div style="text-align:center;height:50px">c6</div></td>
```

when I tried for src of the image I got like

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c9013141-dc8f-40a1-a5bd-4d3ce640af8c", element="49865fbb-0c2a-4bbb-9f9d-67a8c8a5ddd1")>
```

I tried to download the image as

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "abcd.jpg")
```

I got the error as TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

how to download the image from the webpage.

Comment: It seem that you didn't get the image source, but `img` WebElement... Try `urllib.request.urlretrieve(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "ShowImage")]/img').get_attribute('src'), "abcd.jpg") `

Comment: it gives me error ...Error: Bad token: